# tex4ht problem with \includegraphics using beamer class

Tags: beamer, graphics, tex4ht

I have managed to get tex4ht working (on debian jessie) for a moderately complex document (containing muliple \includegraphics, bibliography) with article class. However, for beamer class even the following simple document (t.tex) fails:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\title{Simple beamer doc}
\author{John D}
\date{12 Aug 2014}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{frame title}

  \includegraphics{xml-proc.eps}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

'latex t.tex' works fine but 'mk4ht htlatex t.tex' results in the error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.19 \end{frame}
```

The culprit is `\includegraphics`. Removing `\includegraphics` eliminates above error producing html file with all slides (but obviously no figures). Tried increasing stack size to 50000, but same error. Also, specifying just `\includegraphics{}` (no filename) also produces same error.

A possible hint to the problem may be the following line in the log file (generated by 'mk4ht htlatex t.tex'):

> LaTeX Info: Redefining \includegraphics on input line 16.

Above line is absent in the log file when an article class tex file is used (in which case `\includegraphics` causes no problem).

Any ideas why `\includegraphics` with beamer fails? Else any workaround?

Comment: Can you convert your image and include png or jpg?

Comment: Same problem using png image instead of eps.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find many issues in `tex4ht` support for beamer, because it is really complex package which redefines many commands, which is what `tex4ht` do as well. `\includegraphics` is patched by both `beamer` and `tex4ht`, which creates a conflict. For easy fix of this issue, you may define custom command which will use `\includegraphics` with normal LaTeX and special `tex4ht` command otherwise.

create file `mypic.sty`:

```
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\mypic[1]{\includegraphics{#1}}
\endinput
```

and definition for `tex4ht`, file `mypic.4ht`

```
\renewcommand\mypic[1]{\Picture[picture]{#1}\special{t4ht+@File: #1}}
```

Note that this will work only for pictures supported b web browsers, ie. `png`, `jpg`, `gif` and `svg`.

```
\documentclass[trans]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\title{Simple beamer doc}
\author{John D}
\date{12 Aug 2014}
\usepackage{mypic}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{frame title}

  \mypic{xml-proc.png}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

note that I've added `trans` option to `\documentclass{beamer}`. this suppress creation of multiple slides when `\only` commands are used.

Comment: isn't still there any better solution?

Comment: @user1850133 it seems that `\includegraphics` works out of the box with Beamer now.